# Fazer um select em uma coluna varchar como se fosse datetime SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

O código é o seguinte:

```
    SELECT data 
    FROM lista 
    WHERE data BETWEEN '01-08-2015' 
    AND '05-08-2015';
```

O problema é que a coluna data é um varchar e eu gostaria de usa-la como uma data

Comment: Tente ser mais claro em sua questão

Comment: A coluna data é do tipo varchar. E eu quero usar o between nela como se ela fosse do tipo datetime.

Comment: E qual o erro que deu?

Comment: Se eu mandar o select dessa forma, ele não me retorna nada. Sem erros, mas também não procura valores entre datas porque não é uma data. Tenho que converter esse campo para o tipo datatime antes de fazer o select.

Answer (score 2):

Se for SQL você pode usar a função `convert`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928(v=SQL.120).aspx

SQL

```
SELECT data 
FROM lista 
WHERE data BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01/08/2015', 103)
AND convert(datetime,'05/08/2015',103);
```

MySQL

```
SELECT data 
FROM lista 
WHERE data BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
AND WHERE data BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('05/08/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: Diego

Ele me retorna o seguinte erro: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''01/08/2015',103) AND CONVERT(datetime, '04/08/2015',103) ORDER by protocolo ASC' at line 1

Comment: Coloque a consulta inteira aqui para vermos como está agora. Mas você está usando Sql Server ou MySql. Se for MySql a função é outra.

Comment: Ele me retorna valores entre o mês 07 e o mês 08, quando especifiquei somente mês 08.




        SELECT DATA

        FROM OS

        WHERE DATA BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '01-08-2015', '%d-%m-%Y' ) , '%d-%m-%Y' ) 
        AND DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '05-08-2015', '%d-%m-%Y' ) , '%d-%m-%Y' ) 
        LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Infelizmente o código mysql não funcionou aqui. Tive que mudar a estrutura da coluna pro tipo datatime.

Comment: O que é muito melhor. Trabalhar com o tipo de dados adequado é o correto. Ás vezes por algum motivo não tem como, mas se deve fazer o possível para que os campos sejam específicos para o tipo de trabalho que se irá fazer. Número `int`, `float`, `decimal`. String `varchar`, `text`. Data `datetime`, `timestamp`, `date`. E assim por diante. Isso te ajuda e ajuda o próximo que por ventura vir modificar o sistema.